# jquery-ui accordion issue: panels not expanding on click but expanding on page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Quick question:

I am using jquery-ui accordion 1.8.16. When I tried to expand a panel by clicking it, it just expand a little bit and freeze there. If I refresh the page, the content under that panel is shown. Each panel has its unique id.

What are the possible reasons for this issue?

Comment: @muistooshort I just fixed it. It turned out to be a easing issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my Jquery Fu, I'm sensing that your problem is an easing issue.  You should look into that.